# Struggling with a simple text tooltip when hovering over a photo

Tags: jquery, html, css, tooltip

I want to do this by using jQuery without a plugin.  I want to keep a constant tool tip while hovered over an image.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Very frustrating. Thanks!

HTML

```
    <div class = "runners">
                <h1> Hover to see famous runners</h1>
                <img id = "mo-farah" src="Images/mo-farah.jpg" title = "Mo Farah">
                <img id="paula-radcliffe" src="Images/paula-radcliffe.jpg" title = "Paula Radcliffe">
                <img id = "wilson-kipsang" src="Images/wilson-kipsang.jpg" title = "Wilson Kipsang">

</div>
```

jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    xOffset = 10;
    yOffset = 20;
    $("body").append("<p class = 'runners' id='tooltip'></p>");
    $(document).mousemove(function(evt){
    $("#tooltip")
        .css("top", (evt.pageY + yOffset) + "px")
        .css("left", (evt.pageX + xOffset) + "px"); 
    });

});
```

EDIT

I have changed my HTML and jQuery to try and accommodate what you are saying. But still no joy. Any suggestions?

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    this.tooltip = function(){          
    xOffset = 10;
    yOffset = 20;       
    $("div").hover(function(e){                             
      this.t = this.title;
      this.title = "";                                    
      $("body").append("<p id='tooltip'>"+ this.t +"</p>");
      $("#tooltip")
        .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
        .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
        .fadeIn("fast");        
        },
    function(){
      this.title = this.t;      
      $("#tooltip").remove();
        });             
      };

    $(document).ready(function(){
      tooltip();
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<div class = "runners">
    <h1> Hover to see famous runners</h1>
    <img id = "mo-farah" src="Images/mo-farah.jpg" title = "Mo Farah">
    <img id="paula-radcliffe" src="Images/paula-radcliffe.jpg" title = "Paula Radcliffe">
    <img id = "wilson-kipsang" src="Images/wilson-kipsang.jpg" title = "Wilson Kipsang">
</div>
```

Comment: Question... Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: You have no element `#tooltip` in the markup you provided

Comment: No, just want to use jQuery only.

Comment: @zgood Ah! Where in the HTML should I implement that?

Comment: @zgood That element does exist ....` $("body").append("<p class = 'runners' id='tooltip'></p>");` .... I just doesnt have any content in it and therefore wont be visible by default

Comment: Well I see you actually are appending the `#tooltip` in javascript. You would need to set some styles for it (like `position: absolute;`) and insert actual text into the tooltip because in the code provided it is empty

Comment: @Option that is incorrect. Ids MUST be unique, you cant use `id="tooltip"` on each image. Additionally, the OP only needs one tooltip element in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Your tooltip didn't contain any text, so it was not visible at all. Also, you didn't provide any CSS, but the tooltip of course has to be positoned absolutely.

What you need to implement further is:

- Only show the tooltip when hovering over an element where it's desired to be shown
- Hide the tooltip when leaving such an element
- Change your tooltip content depending on which element is hovered

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    xOffset = 10;
    yOffset = 20;
    $tooltip = $("<p class='runners' id='tooltip'>Tooltip text</p>").hide().appendTo(document.body);
    
    // the callback function handling the tooltip movement
    function moveTooltip(evt){
      $tooltip
        .css("top", (evt.pageY + yOffset) + "px")
        .css("left", (evt.pageX + xOffset) + "px"); 
    }
    
    $('[data-tooltip]').on('mouseenter', function() {
      // register mousemove event handler
      $(document).on("mousemove.tooltip", moveTooltip);
      // set tooltip content from data attribute
      $tooltip.html($(this).attr('data-tooltip'));
      // show tooltip
      $tooltip.show();
    });
    
    $('[data-tooltip]').on('mouseleave', function() {
      // un-register mousemove event handler
      $(document).off("mousemove.tooltip");
      // hide tooltip
      $tooltip.hide();
    });

});
```

```css
#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "runners">
  <h1> Hover to see famous runners</h1>
  <img id="mo-farah" src="Images/mo-farah.jpg" title="Mo Farah" data-tooltip="Tooltip Content 1">
  <img id="paula-radcliffe" src="Images/paula-radcliffe.jpg" title= "Paula Radcliffe" data-tooltip="Second Tooltip Content">
  <img id="wilson-kipsang" src="Images/wilson-kipsang.jpg" title="Wilson Kipsang" data-tooltip="And now for something <em>completely</em> different.">
</div>
```

Comment: You're gonna need to limit this to only show the tooltip when you hover over *the image* ....not the whole page

Comment: Have you read my full answer? ;) That's actually the first point in my list.

Comment: Have you read the question? "I want to keep a constant tool tip *while hovered over an image.*"

Comment: This is so super, thank you. How could I apply this tool tip specifically to one of the images, however? Presumably I would have to create 3 separate pieces of jQuery (for the 3 separate images)?

Comment: FYI, I read this answer as "here's half of what you asked, go figure out the rest on your own". That's why I downvoted, you intentionally only answered the easy bit of the question.

Comment: @KaliMa you could add handlers for `$('img').on('mouseenter')` and `$('img').on('mouseleave')`. On mouse enter, get the desired tooltip content from a data attribute of the image for example and show the tooltip, then hide it again on mouse leave.

Comment: So what's holding you back posting a fully working code? And what do you think from which approach OP will have a better learning effect?

Comment: I have updated the code, but still no joy. Please provide any guidance that you can.

Comment: I updated my answer to implement the steps that were still missing to reach your goal. So maybe now @DelightedD0D is satisfied as well... ;-)

Comment: Indeed, your answer now answers the question asked ;)